# Can't access public dns EC2

Tags: url, amazon-ec2, webserver

I have created an ec2 instance of ubuntu. I have installed apache. I tried to access public dns via browser, but can't connect to url.

Comment: Check your firewall and security group settings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the port on which your apache is running in the security group. 
After doing that, you will be able to access your application.